# adding variables and console.log the result

Tags: javascript

I'm taking a basic javascript tutorial and cannot figure this out as I've been searching and searching.

Code is as follows:

```
const a = 1
const b = 1

console.log("a" + "b");
```

This *should* return 2, but something is wrong.  Fix the code.

I've tried many different options including removing the quotes and changing const to var or let with no luck.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are printing a string and not the variables 'a' or 'b'. You should do `console.log(a + b)', without the quotes

Comment: And missing `;` between the two const

Comment: try console.log(a + b); also read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp
a and b are variables and you should not write in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing 'a' and 'b' as strings by using the double quotes, which is why your code doesn't work as intended. You also did not add a semicolon between your variable declarations. You should do `console.log(a + b)`, without the quotes:

```
const a = 1; 
const b = 1;

console.log(a + b); // 2
```

Please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) on medium, which explains the differences between `let`, `const` and `var`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't add the double quotes. That will print a string.

You want to print a sum of numbers so a+b would suffice.

```
console.log(a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you cannot add two variables with quotes. Your console.log("a" + "b") would print 'ab' as it's treated as a string. 
Also, you need to add a semicolon (;) after you declare a const.

```js
const a=1, b=1; //add a ';'

console.log(a+b); //will output 2 as it has no quotes
```